# a = 0; why (++a + ++a * ++a) = 7?

Tags: java, increment

```
public class Latihan
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int a = 0;
        System.out.println(++a + ++a * ++a);
    }
}
```

The output is 7. What is happening here?
Please explain me. I'm still a newbie in programming.

Comment: What do you think it should be and why?

Comment: so you think `1 + 2 * 3` is not `7`?

Comment: So, it does the increment first?

Comment: Yes, because it's **pre**-increment.

Comment: This is a legitimate question to ask, but if you're new to programming, I'd also like to point out that you should avoid using this sort of construct (multiple pre-increments on the same variable in the same expression) at all cost (even when you are more experienced). This just makes the code confusing for everyone (and this behaviour wouldn't necessarily be the same in other languages). (... cont'd ...)

Comment: (...) Here is a [piece of advice from the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7) about the Evaluation Order: "*It is recommended that code not rely crucially on this specification. Code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side effect, as its outermost operation, and when code does not depend on exactly which exception arises as a consequence of the left-to-right evaluation of expressions.*"

Comment: evaluation order is covered by [section 15.7 of the language specifiction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)

Answer (score 10):

This is what happened:

```
++a + ++a * ++a
  1 +   2 *   3
  1 + 6
  7
```

**EDIT 2**

```
++a + a++ * ++a
  1 + 1   *   3
  1 + 3
  4
```

- `++a` means increment the value of `a` **before** using it, thus the **pre**-increment
- `a++` means use the value of `a` **then** increment it, thus the **post**-increment

[Read more about operator precedence here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: Thank you. So it does the increment first? I thought it does the multiplication first.

Comment: @ThoyibAntarnusa Yes, it does the increment first. I provided a link for the operator precedence in my answer. You can check that out for more information. :)

Answer (score 1):

++a means "increment the value of a, returning the *new (incremented)* value". So, yes, the increment occurs before you have the value available to work with.

If that isn't what you wanted...

a++ means "increment the value of a, returning the *previous (un-incremented)* value".

```
int a=0;
System.out.println(++a); /* will print 1, and leave a set to 1 */
a=0;
System.out.println(a++); /* will print 0, and leave a set to 1 */
```

Similarly for the '--a' and 'a--' (decrement) operators.

Java expressions don't get *quite* as hairy as C expressions could, since Java doesn't have pointer manipulation operators, but there are still enough operators to make precedence confusing at times. That's especially true when side-effects are involved, as in this case. When in doubt -- or when you think the next person to read the code might be in doubt -- you may want to pull the increment out of the expression and perform it separately.